# How does one put on a 2s10s trade using 2 and 10 year treasury futures contracts when the CTDs are not 2 and 10 year bonds?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, futures, spread

The CME describes how to put on a 2s10s trade in this screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yPzW.jpg

Looking at current 2 and 10 year futures the CTD is roughly a 2 year and 7 year respectively.

Am I right in saying that using the current 2 and 10 year futures to put on a 2s10s trade, you're actually not capturing the spread between the 2 year yield and the 10 year yield?  It's more the 2 and 7 year yield spread?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [contract specs](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/interest-rates/us-treasury/10-year-us-treasury-note.contractSpecs.html) of the 10 Year Treasury Note ("TY") future, you can deliver any UST

> with a remaining term to maturity of at least six and a half years, but not more than 10 years, from the first day of the delivery month.

So yes, TY is typically closer to a 7 year UST than a 10 year.

Perhaps you can look at [UXY](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/us-treasury/ultra-10.html), the 10y Ultra Future, which is closer to 10 years with a minimum remaining maturity of 9 years and 5 months.

The pool of deliverable bonds for TY (currently around 18) is much wider than for UXY (currently 2).